# how to make this find specific extensions and show only the file name

Tags: php

1) how can i make this read only ".txt" files

2) how can i make it show only the file name so i can design it how i'd i like..
(`<h1>$file</h1>` for example)

```
$dir = "includes/news";
$dh = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
{
    if ($filename != "." && $filename != ".." && strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1)) == 'txt')
    {
    $files[] = $filename;
    }
}
sort($files);
echo $files;
```

what it shows right now is:

> Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => [23.7] Hey.txt [3] => [24.7] New
>   Website.txt [4] => [25.7] Example.txt )

Now, this is another way i could do it, i like it bit better:

```
        if( $handle = opendir( 'includes/news' )) 
    {
        while( $file = readdir( $handle )) 
        {
            if( strstr( $file, "txt" ) )
            {
                $addr = strtr($file, array('.txt' => ''));
                echo '<h1><a href="?module=news&read=' . $addr . '">&raquo; ' . $addr . "</a></h1>";
            }
         }
        closedir($handle);
    }
```

but the my issue with this one is that there is no Sorting between the files.
everything is ok with the output, just the order of them. so if one of you can figure out how to sort them right, that would be perfect

Comment: Show us some code you've already tried. I bet you have some

Comment: i added another way i tried doing it, its in the bottom. could you check it please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, try this:

```
$files = array();
if($handle = opendir( 'includes/news' )) {
    while( $file = readdir( $handle )) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            // let's check for txt extension
            $extension = substr($file, -3);
            // filename without '.txt'
            $filename = substr($file, 0, -4);
            if ($extension == 'txt')
                $files[] = $file; // or $filename
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
sort($files);
foreach ($files as $file)
    echo '<h1><a href="?module=news&read=' . $file 
        . '">&raquo; ' . $file . "</a></h1>";
```

Comment: the sorting here is good! it works, and it shows exactly what i needed. but the problem is that it's reversed, can i change sort to rsort? also, the .txt extension is still there. it shows [23.7] Hey.txt

Comment: Use `rsort` if you want. And put `$filename` instead of `$file` in `$files` as I wrote in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should accomplish what you want to do. It uses explode and a negative limit to find only .txt files and returns only the name.

```
$dir = "includes/news";
$dh = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))){

    $fileName = explode('.txt', $node, -1)[0];
    if(count($fileName) )
        $files[] = '<h1>'.$fileName.'</h1>';

}
```

Comment: thanks, not by me tho. ok so i tried it, i added $dh = "includes/news"; which is the folder, but the error i get is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: Array dereferencing available since php5.4.

Answer (score 0):

try to make it as simple as possible
try this

```
function check_txt($file){
 $array = explode(".","$file");
 if(count($array)!=1 && $array[count($array)-1]=="txt"){return true;}
 return false;
  }
if($handle = opendir( 'includes/news' )) {
 while( $file = readdir( $handle )) 
    {
        if( check_txt($file) )
        {
            echo '<h1><a href="?module=news&read=' . $file . '">&raquo; ' . $file . "</a></h1>";
        }
     }
    closedir($handle);
}
```